# Facebook Access Tokens and Multiple Access Points

Tags: facebook

I'm new to developing applications that use Facebook's API and I haven't quite found a scenario similar to this so hopefully someone can shed some more light on this.

Scenario:

There is an booth running a tablet with an Android application that scans unique identifiers for the users (eg: a personalized card with a unique QR code which has their id that is linked to their Facebook access token) users can post photos from the tablet application to their feed from this Facebook app.

Before the event they'd register on the site and link their Facebook account so they can get their personalized invitation.

So the process:

1. Register on a website and link their Facebook account to my Facebook application.
2. Get a personalized item with a unique QR code
3. Scan QR code at tablet and let them post photos/updates to their FB wall after a scan
4. Auto sign-out after a post

I read that access tokens are good for about an hour, however I saw they offered a long-term one which is good for up to 60 days. This whole process is about 2 weeks so that would be more than sufficient. I was just wondering if something like this is even possible and if it isn't what would be a good work around?

Answer (score 0):

You can exchange the short-lived Access Token for a long-lived one. See the docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#termtokens and here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending